# Authorization for tcodes created for table maintenance

Tags: abap

Would appreciate if you could answer my questions:

1) If I created a Z transaction code for maintaining a Z table that has authorization group not equals to `&NC&` and data browser/table view maint is set to `Display/Maintenance Allowed with restriction`,  Does that mean the Z tcode will also be restricted to few users?

2) Is there a way to know who are authorized to run a certain Z Tcode created for maintaining a table?

Comment: For the latter use SUIM tcode

Answer (score 1):

Ad. 1.) No, it won't.
Ad. 2.) Yes, there is.

Comment: At least youu should have been give a hint how to accomplish pt. 2:)

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this in SUIM go like this: *User* -> *Users by Complex Selection Criteria* -> *By Transaction Authorizations*

[image]

There enter tcode and press F8.